# ng serve and ng build gives different results in style

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm setting up a Django backend and using Angular as front end. I'm pretty new at this, so sorry if this is an easy question. I couldn't find anything on it. I'm testing the styling for Angular by using `ng serve` and accessing `localhost:4200`. I finally got it looking how I want to, and then I run `ng build` to put the static file on django/heroku and the styling is completely off! I tried doing `ng build --aot` but that didn't really work either.

I checked the elements in console between built and served, I can see that the `font weight` changed from `700` to `bold`, container color from `#fff` to `white`. but what's throwing it off the most are these `"Pseudo ::before element"` and `"Pseudo ::after element"`. Some of the other areas have even changed font altogether. The one from `ng serve` has font `inherited from body` `"Montserrat"`, the one from `ng build` has the font `inherited from body`, but it's crossed out? I've attached a picture as an example.

[image]

Left for ng serve, right for ng build

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I had this in the index file that was overwriting what I had in angular.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Removed it and it works :)

Answer (score -1):

```
use this command npm install bootstrap@3.3.7
 and add bootstrap package in angular.json

"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "styles.scss"
]
if any problem related to style then go to this link
https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/
```